# Random and sudden logging out from my user session

Tags: logout

I've an issue with ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04. I'm logged out from my user session randomly and suddenly.

Here are some log information:

> kern.log

first logout:

```
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work kernel: [28558.808129] traps: metacity[7712] trap int3 ip:7fe10cb50d00 sp:7ffdb4f06a00 error:0
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: Unrecoverable failure in required component metacity.desktop
May  3 16:35:12 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: Entering running state
```

second logout:

```
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work kernel: [54634.236474] traps: metacity[30179] trap int3 ip:7f68e3eddd00 sp:7ffc5e2b9d30 error:0
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: Unrecoverable failure in required component metacity.desktop
May  4 00:50:42 rm-work gnome-session[27957]: Entering running state
```

> syslog.log

first log out:

```
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: Avertissement du gestionnaire de fenêtres : Log level 6: The program 'metacity' received an X Window System error.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: This probably reflects a bug in the program.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: The error was 'BadRegion (invalid Region parameter)'.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: (Details: serial 63596288 error_code 140 request_code 138 (XFIXES) minor_code 12)
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work kernel: [28558.808129] traps: metacity[7712] trap int3 ip:7fe10cb50d00 sp:7ffdb4f06a00 error:0
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: Child process 7712 was already dead.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: Child process 7712 was already dead.
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: Application 'metacity.desktop' killed by signal 5
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: App 'metacity.desktop' respawning too quickly
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: Application 'metacity.desktop' killed by signal 5
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: gnome-session[7637]: WARNING: App 'metacity.desktop' respawning too quickly
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: Unrecoverable failure in required component metacity.desktop
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May  3 16:34:59 rm-work gnome-session[7637]: gnome-session[7637]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

> second log out:

```
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: Avertissement du gestionnaire de fenêtres : Log level 6: The program 'metacity' received an X Window System error.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: This probably reflects a bug in the program.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: The error was 'BadRegion (invalid Region parameter)'.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: (Details: serial 170024023 error_code 140 request_code 138 (XFIXES) minor_code 12)
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work kernel: [54634.236474] traps: metacity[30179] trap int3 ip:7f68e3eddd00 sp:7ffc5e2b9d30 error:0
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: Child process 30179 was already dead.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: Child process 30179 was already dead.
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: Application 'metacity.desktop' killed by signal 5
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: Application 'metacity.desktop' killed by signal 5
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: App 'metacity.desktop' respawning too quickly
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: gnome-session[30100]: WARNING: App 'metacity.desktop' respawning too quickly
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: Unrecoverable failure in required component metacity.desktop
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May  4 00:50:24 rm-work gnome-session[30100]: gnome-session[30100]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Any idea to fix it?

Regards

Comment: Type Ctrl-Alt-F1 and login to a terminal session. `sudo grep metacity /var/spool/log/*`

Comment: @Aliot Any errors in the Xorg logs could also help will the trouble shooting.  `sudo grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: did you try dpkg-reconfigure metacity? (never done mysef, but if it fail, maybe the problem is metacity or server X configuration)

Comment: this is exactly like what my friend faced. and he notice that his session always suddenly logged out if he runs Chrome. did you experiencing this while running a specific program? this is indeed a bug. in your case it seems 'metacity'. try using another windows manager program.

Comment: can we have some hardware specific info please open a terminal and type lspci then post output please. Also have you installed any themes or modified the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

This is unresolved, but relatively rare bug, if you are using gnome-flashback session. Partly because mostly all are using default UI.
See more details and subscribe to see if problem is resolved here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1455916

Temporary fix - don't use gnome-flashback session.